# Post request not showing any results in Postman

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, post, postman

src/server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Note = require("./model/Note");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://shubhankarpande:FDqVzMK6drkgfXwX@cluster0.cepyiu9.mongodb.net/notesDB").then(()=> {

// home route
app.get('/',(req,res)=> {
    res.send("Home Page");
});
var notes
app.get('/notes/list/:userid',async (req,res)=> {
     notes = await Note.find({ userid : req.params.userid });    // array to store all notes
    res.json(notes);
});

// post route does not understand URL encoded/ JSON data
app.post('/notes/add', async(req,res) => {
        res.json(req.body);
        console.log(res.body);
});

});

app.listen(5000,()=> {
    console.log("Server started at port 5000");
});
```

src/models/Note.js

```
/*
Steps :
1. Define Schema ---> Note : id, userid,title, content ,dateadded
2. Create Model and exporting ---> <model name> <schema> Note
*/
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// 1.  Defining the Schema
const noteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    userid : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
    },
    title : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
    },
    content : {
        type : String,
    },
    dateadded: {
        type : Date,
        default : Date.now,
    }
});

// 2. Creating a mongoose model and exporting
module.exports = mongoose.model("Note",noteSchema)
```

This is a simple rest API for managing notes, and I am unable to post the data, whenever I am trying to post some data from Postman , it is returning a NULL value. No errors are there. After consoling the input it is returning undefined values and not the posted values.

[image: The post request in returing an empty array even after posting the data.]

Comment: Remove your username and password from your cluster connection string in this post as anyone can connect to your database. After you do this change your password.

Comment: You are incorrectly logging `console.log(res.body);` when it should be `req.body`. Also change `bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false})` to `true`. Move all of your routes outside of the `then` block of the connection.